# Extracting acronyms from each string in list index

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings (the other posts only had single words or ints) that are imported from a file and I am having trouble using nested loops to separate each few words in an index into its own list and then taking the first letters of each to create acronyms.

I have tried picking apart each index and processing it through another loop to get the first letter of each word but the closest I got was pulling every first letter from each indexes from the original layer.

```
text = (infile.read()).splitlines()
    acronym = []
    separator = "."
    for i in range(len(text)):
        substring = [text[i]]
        for j in range(len(substring)):
            substring2 = [substring[j][:1])]
            acronym.append(substring2)
            print("The Acronym is: ", separator.join(acronym))
```

Happy Path: The list of multi-word strings will turn be translated into acronyms that are listed with linebreaks. 
Example of what should output at the end: D.O.D. \n N.S.A. \n ect.

What's happened so far: Before I had gotten it to take the first letter of the first word of every index at the sentence level but I haven't figured out how to nest these loops to get to the single words of each index.

Useful knowledge: THE BEGINNING FORMAT AFTER SPLITLINES (Since people couldn't read this)  is a list with indexes with syntax like this: ['Department of Defense', 'National Security Agency', ...]

Comment: It is customary to include pasted in sample data, current output and expected output.  Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it from a file. File format was like this:

['This is Foo', 'Coming from Bar', 'Bring Your Own Device', 'Department of Defense']

So if this also helps anyone, enjoy~

```
infile = open(iname, 'r')
        text = (infile.read()).splitlines()
        print("The Strings To Become Acronyms Are As Followed: \n", text, "\n")
        acronyms = []
        for string in text:
            words = string.split()
            letters = [word[0] for word in words]
            acronyms.append(".".join(letters).upper())

        print("The Acronyms For These Strings Are: \n",acronyms)
```

This code outputs like this:

The Strings To Become Acronyms Are As Followed:

['This is Foo', 'Coming from Bar', 'Bring Your Own Device', 'Department of Defense']

The Acronyms For These Strings Are:

['T.I.F', 'C.F.B', 'B.Y.O.D', 'D.O.D']

Comment: I think this can be added to the base python program as another method for string manipulation. For example: some_string.acronym()

Answer (score 2):

What you have is kind of a mess. If you are going to be re-using code, it is often better to just make it into a function. Try this out.

```
def get_acronym(the_string):
    words = the_string.split(" ")
    return_string = ""
    for word in words:
        return_string += word[0]
    return return_string

text = ['Department of Defense', 'National Security Agency']
for agency in text:
    print("The acronym is: " + get_acronym(agency))
```

Comment: It's part of a bigger program that unfortunately has to read from the diff. file.

Comment: Doesn't this work with your beginning format though? `['Department of Defense', 'National Security Agency', ...]`?  And you just need to add a dot after each += of the return string.